# JQuery image hover and click conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I am trying to make a zoom in effect on an image on hover and on click, the image should stay enlarged. I have a set of 5 images, and everytime I hover on each one of them, they zoom in properly and as I move my mouse, they zoom out just like I want them.

The problem is when I try to select an image. When I do this, the image should get slightly larger and stay as is and not decrease in size and go back to normal. This is where I think is the conflict between the `hover` and `click` function. Also, when I select another image, the other image which was previously zoomed in(selected) should get back to it's original size but this is also not working now due to this conflict.

I have done some searching around S.O but can't find anything that's helping me.

**Below is my code:**

```
//Item hover

$(".anItem").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('transition');    
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('transition');
});

//Select Item

$(".anItem").click(function(){  
    $(".anItem").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("selectedItem");
    });
    if($(this).hasClass("selectedItem")){
        $(this).removeClass("selectedItem");
        itemColor = "";
    }else{
        itemColor = $(this).data("color");
        $(this).addClass("selectedItem");
        $("#oneBtn").show();
    }                           
});
```

**CSS**

```
.anItem{
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    -o-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.anItem{
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
/*
.anItem:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
*/
.selectedItem{
    width: 230px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: remove the code for each inside click function and should work fine as your requirement.

Comment: can you maybe add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wants something like this ?

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozekc13n/1/)

I've simplified your JS code like this :

```
$(function(){
  //Select Item
  $(".anItem").click(function(){  
    $('div').find('img').addClass('anItem');
    $(this).removeClass("anItem");   
  });
});
```

The `:hover` part is done with CSS only in my code.

Comment: This solution is great. Worked perfect. Thanks

Comment: I tried to replace anItem with selectedItem, and it doesn't work. Why is that the case?

Comment: Mh don't know, can you show me a JSFiddle of this ?